# jquery navigate + highlight <li> items on key.code pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, user-interface

Hi i'm planning to make a ul li list and make it navigable highlighting the `<li>` items

so starting from:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a class="a">hey</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="a">hey you!</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="a">hey what's up?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="a">hey hey</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

i would like to navigate `<li>` items in this way:

1. User clicks key 'down' (as for autocomplete lists) and he enter the `<ul></ul>`
2. User clicks key left/right and he highlight the +1 or -1 `<li>` item
3. User clicks key up and he exit the `<ul></ul>`

is there someone can help me on doing this?

ohohoho :) i just founded the perfect example : take a look at stackoverflow tags input autocomplete list :) (it's the same thing i would like to do for my ul item :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where exactly you want to listen for `keydown` events, but this works for the entire `document`:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function (e) {
    var $prev, $next, $current = $("ul li.highlight");

    if (e.which === 40 && !$current.length) {
        $("ul li:first").addClass("highlight");
    } else if (e.which === 39) {
        $next = $current.next("li");
        if ($next.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $next.addClass("highlight");
        }

    } else if (e.which === 37) {
        $prev = $current.prev("li");
        if ($prev.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $prev.addClass("highlight");
        }
    } else if (e.which === 38) {
        $("ul li").removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WeNdW/

Comment: excellent, just check this : first click key.down then click key.left or key.right then click key.down once more :P

Comment: @Ispuk: I wasn't sure what you wanted to occur in this case. What should happen?

Comment: tomorrow i will accept the right answer,for now maxedison's is better, cause of your little bug, if fixed i'd preferr your version, cause also of less line of code , really thx!

Comment: don't you see there are 2 highlighted <li> ? :P

Comment: firs click down highlight first <li> , then key.down will have no effects :)

Comment: I don't see two highlighted `li` elements on IE9, FF 6, Chrome, or Safari on Win7...

Comment: @Ispuk: That bug did exist on my earliest version of this answer. Are you sure you're looking at the most recent jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/8Tg4H/

Comment: i choosed your version need only to check on all browsers